# Negating POSIX class bash globbing

Tags: bash, posix, glob

I am curious if I could negate POSIX class while performing pattern matching.
I have following:

```
file  file1  file10  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

Say, I want to ls -l only file : all the files with no digit in the end.
I tried following :

```
ls -l *[^[[:digit:]]]
ls -l *[!digits]
ls -l *[[!:digit:]]
```

None of above works. That actually work, to some extend (I get file10):

```
ls *[^1-9]
```

But that's not a point. And for the record I know that the easiest would be:

```
ls -l | egrep -v ".*[[:digit:]]$"
```

Is there any way to negate POSIX class?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `*[^[:digit:]]` to match files not ending with digits:

```
printf "%s\n" *[^[:digit:]]
file
```

Comment: Thx, I see what you did there.

Comment: Technically the POSIX spec for negation in filename expansion uses [`!` instead of `^`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01).

Answer (score 4):

The outer square brackets denote the character class. The inner ones denote the POSIX class. Negate the character class:

```
ls -l *[^[:digit:]]
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Technically the POSIX spec for negation in filename expansion uses [`!` instead of `^`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01).